# Useful resource for scala scripting

Tags: scala, scripting, resources

I would love to be able to find a resource for a good intro to scala scripting. Something that covers using library dependencies properly, and examples for executing system processes and handling input/output correctly.

I have found bits and pieces on the web, but nothing really useful as a solid reference for a beginner. Perhaps there's a chapter in one of the many scala books out there that I've yet to find.

Any help in tracking something like this down would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the standard package [scala.sys](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.sys.package)

This package was added to Scala 2.9 and contains utilities migrated from the compiler and sbt to help with system tasks and scripting. It contains access to system properties, environment variables, the runtime, threads and last but not least processes with a Scala ProcessBuilder and other tools.

For scripting you might also consider the scalax [Scala-io](http://jesseeichar.github.com/scala-io-doc/0.4.0/index.html#!/overview) libraries, which may soon be distributed with Scala. These libraries support good abstractions for I/O, filesystems, paths and files and use automatic resource management, path sets, globbing and other useful features.

Answer (score 0):

You can write any code you want into a script with .scala extension. There is no difference to write "normal" code. You can execute the code after saving as usual. 
Notice that the most IDE do not support scripting.

 Here is a [link](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-as-a-scripting-language) to an article, describing the topic.